# How can I create foreign data wrapper dynamically using postgresql stored procedure? I have tried but it shown syntax error

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, database-administration

Here I just wanted to create postgres_fdw in dynamically but unable to do it due to syntax error. I passed parameter into a stored procedure but postgres not understand it is as a variable.

Anyone check my code, where should I need to change?

```
create procedure remote_db_connection_creator(
        remote_server varchar(100),
        remote_host varchar(100),
        remote_port integer,
        remote_dbane varchar(100),
        remote_table varchar(100),
        remote_user varchar(100),
        repmte_user_pass varchar(100),
        remote_schemma_name varchar(100)='public'
        local_schemma_name varchar(100)='public'
    )
language plpgsql
as $$
declare dbusername text := current_user;
begin
    CREATE EXTENSION postgres_fdw;
    CREATE SERVER remote_server FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw OPTIONS (host remote_host, dbname remote_db, port remote_port);
    CREATE USER MAPPING FOR dbusername SERVER remote_server OPTIONS (user user_remote_user, password repmte_user_pass);
    IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA remote_schemma_name LIMIT TO (remote_table) FROM SERVER remote_server INTO local_schemma_name;
end; $$
```

[image: syntax error]

Comment: Parameters can only be used in `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statements. You will have to use `format` to construct a string for the `CREATE FOREIGN TABLE` statement and `EXECUTE` that string.

Comment: Is it correct format ?
declare dbusername text := current_user;
begin
 CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgres_fdw;
 EXECUTE   FORMAT('CREATE SERVER %s FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw OPTIONS (host %s , port %I)', remote_server,remote_host, remote_port);
 EXECUTE   FORMAT('CREATE USER MAPPING FOR %s SERVER %s OPTIONS (user %s,password %s)', dbusername,remote_server, remote_user,remote_user_pass);
 EXECUTE   FORMAT('IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA %s LIMIT TO (%s) FROM SERVER %s INTO ', remote_schemma_name,remote_table,remote_server,local_schemma_name);
end; $$

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "192.168"
LINE 1: ...3 FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw OPTIONS (host 192.168.43...   
@ Laurenz Albe

Comment: Not `%s`. For string literals, use `%L`. For identifiers (table names etc.), use `%I`.

Comment: My update code is here =====================================EXECUTE   FORMAT('CREATE SERVER %s FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw OPTIONS (host %L, port %L, dbname %L)', remote_server,remote_host, remote_port, remote_dbname);
    EXECUTE   FORMAT('CREATE USER MAPPING FOR %s SERVER %s OPTIONS (user %L,password %L)', dbusername,remote_server, remote_user,remote_user_pass);
 EXECUTE   FORMAT('IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA %s LIMIT TO (%s) FROM SERVER %s INTO %s', remote_schemma_name,remote_table,remote_server,local_schemma_name);